# How can I move a character from one point to a specific point at any desired speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used from this code but it does not do it:

```
public Transform[] points;
public float speed;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "door1") 
    {       
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, points[1].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

That is, I want the pig to go to a higher point on the ground at a desired speed when it hits the trigger (see the photo attached to see it)

[image: How can I move a character from one point to a specific point at any desired speed?]

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here:

- you are calling that line exactly **once** when you enter the collider so the movement is applied for **I single frame**!
- Lerp interpolates linear between two positions using a factor between `0` and `1`. You every time use the current position as start point so what *would* happen if if you called this continuously is approximating the position getting slower and slower every frame which is not what you describe. You want to move with a constant speed.

You most likely would rather use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and [`MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) for that

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    // Better use CompareTag here
    if (other.CompareTag("door1"))
    {     
        // Start a routine for the continuous movement
        StartCoroutine(MoveTo(points[1].position, speed);
    }
}

private IEnumerator MoveTo(Vector3 targetPosition, float linearSpeed)
{
    // This uses an approximation of 0.00001 for equality
    while(transform.position != targetPosition)
    {
        // with a constant speed of linearSpeed Units / second
        // move towards the target position without overshooting
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, linearSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Tell Unity to "pause" the routine here, render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // to be sure to end up with exact values set the target position fix when done
    transform.position = targetPosition;
}
```

---

Alternatively a bit more complex looking but more powerful would be to rather calculate the required time depending on the speed but still adding some smoothing like e.g.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("door1"))
    {     
        StartCoroutine (MoveTo(points[1].position, speed);
    }
}

private IEnumerator MoveTo(Vector3 targetPosition, float averageSpeed)
{ 
    // store the initial position
    var from = transform.position;
    // Get the expected duration depending on distance and speed
    var duration = Vector3.Distance(from, targetPosition) / averageSpeed;

    // This is increased over time
    var timePassed = 0;
    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
        // This linear grows from 0 to 1
        var factor = timePassed / duration;
        // Adds some ease-in and ease-out at beginning and end of the movement
        factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

        // linear interpolate on the smoothed factor 
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(from, targetPosition, factor);

        // increase by time passed since last frame
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        // Tell Unity to "pause" the routine here, render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // to be sure to end up with exact values set the target position fix when done
    transform.position = targetPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnTriggerEnter2D` is only called once on every collider enter. Given you are only moving it by `speed * Time.deltaTime` with Time.deltaTime being in the order of 0.008 - 0.100 it may only move slightly.

Depending on what you want, are you sure you don't want to completely move the object or alternatively set a flag that starts moving it in the update() method?